# How can I tell if a certain Active Directory login has been used today?

Tags: active-directory, domain, login

How can I tell if a somebody used the login 'Accounts' today to log into a pc in my Active Directory domain?  It seems to be causing errors if 2 people are logged in using the same username and I don't know if this is the case or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To see the last time a particular account has logged in to your domain, you can run the net user command via a command prompt. Syntax is as follows (without the brackets):

`net user [username] [/domain]`

That will return several pieces of information, including Last logon time.

Comment: so i would put net user accounts /myersclark  ans sorry is there a way it would tell me what computer it was logged into?

Comment: No, you would put:

net user accounts /domain

Comment: it will not let me vote up i will do when i get enough points

Answer (score 1):

With Active Directory a user can be logged into different workstations without causing problems.  What are the issues you are seeing?  If you have the proper auditing on your DCs you could search through the event logs for login events for that user.

A more accurate answer could be given if you provide more information on what OS you are running on your DCs and what Domain & Forest Function level you are running.

You could also use the [Lockout Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=7af2e69c-91f3-4e63-8629-b999adde0b9e&displaylang=en) to search the username if your problem is related to the account getting locked out.  It will search the event logs for bad logon attempts on the DCs and show you the most recent attempt.

Comment: sorry i dont no what a forest function is. my domain in called myersclark and it is run on a server 2003. i have software that runs on my printers so when u scan a document it sends it to the computer where the person is logged in. i have a tempory account called Accounts and when i scan something half of the document appears and the other disappers which makes me think that there are 2 users logged in useing this so i was wondering if there is say a log of when users have logged in

Comment: You would need to look through the Security event log on the DC of your domain for login events.  However, to test you could reset the password of that account so only you know it, or create a new temp account and test with that one.

Comment: it will not let me vote up i will do when i get enough points